# postgresql cast numeric to date and format

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion, to-date

I have my date field as numeric in postgresql and the values in the date are like 1401710352000 and when I try to convert it using to_timestamp(date) then I get the corresponding timestamp as "46388-06-07 10:40:00+00"

I have tried to google it and I have found quite useful functions on how to do different type conversions in postgresql but i could not find how to cast a numeric date to a proper readable format. i will apprecaite if someone can tell me how to convert a numeric date field to a timestamp/date readable format

Shah

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE):

> `to_timestamp(double precision)`
>   timestamp with time zone
>   convert Unix epoch to time stamp

A Unix epoch is in seconds but it looks like your numeric value is in milliseconds. If we fix the units, then we get something that looks reasonable:

```
=> select to_timestamp(1401710352000::numeric/1000);
      to_timestamp      
------------------------
 2014-06-02 04:59:12-07
```

So you probably just need to fix the units by dividing by 1000 before you call `to_timestamp`.

Comment: the date fomat came correct but still the date converted is coming wrong..  to_timestamp(1505468541312:numeric/1000) ..... it should be currentdate i.e. 2017-09-25 ....but it coming 2017-09-15

Comment: what is :: here in the above casting?

Comment: @JGS Yes, `::` is a typecast, same thing as `cast(1401710352000 as numeric)`, otherwise the `/` would be integer division. Why would you expect `1505468541312` to be the current date? The current date in the above format would be `1506297600000`.

Comment: when I inserted a record in the existing database table it inserted this value as 1505468541312 for the current date

Comment: @JGS How specifically did you insert it? When did you insert it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the field 'fecha' in seconds.. and I had to converted it to date to be able to compare it (formatting it). I did it like that this:

```
select to_char(to_timestamp(fecha),'DD/MM/YYYY') from...
```